# Cassandra Spark Connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

My cassandra CF has date and id as partition Key .
while querying I only know the date , so I loop over range of id's .

My question revolves around how the connector executes the following code.

SparkDriver code looks like -

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DemoApp")
.conf.setMaster("local[*]")
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.*.*.*")
.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "*");

JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SparkContextJavaFunctions javaFunctions = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc);

String date = "23012017";

for(String id : idlist) {

JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRowsRDD = 

javaFunctions.cassandraTable("datakeyspace", "sample2")
            .where("date = ?",date)
            .where("id = ? ", id)
            .select("data");

 cassandraRowsRDDList.add(cassandraRowsRDD);
}

List<CassandraRow> collectAllRows = new ArrayList<CassandraRow>();
        for(JavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd : cassandraRowsRDDList){
            //do transformations

            collectAllRows.addAll(rdd.collect());
    }
```

1) First of all I wanted to ask if I loop over the idlist ,say idlist has 1000 elements which might be increasing ever , will this be efficient ? how each select query be distributed in the cluster ?Especially how Cassandra DB connections will be maintained ?

2) In my driver program After looping over I am putting All the rows in List , and then apply transformations to each row and filter out the duplicates . Will this also be distributed by spark on the cluster or will this take place at driver's side .

Kindly help .!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way of doing this provided by spark cassandra connector.
you can create a rdd of (date,id) and then call joinWithCassandraTable function on columns date and id. Connector do it smartly all the data will be fetched by the workers only and that too without shuffle that is each worker will fetch the data only for the date and id it is having.